# writing methodinfo or assembly type to file

Tags: c#

I was given some code that was in c#. The only thing it did was decompress an embed assembly and execute it. I was wondering how I could write this executing assembly to file to recover it.

```
public static object RunIt()
{
    Type[] types = DeliverUs.Assembly.GetTypes();
    for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    {
        Type type = types[i];
        MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods();
        for (int j = 0; j < methods.Length; j++)
        {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = methods[j];
            if (methodInfo.Name == DeliverUs.Name)
            {
                return methodInfo.Invoke(null, DeliverUs.Values);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have already tried AssemblyBuilder to no success. How should I tackle this and write the assembly to a local file? MemoryStream?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize Assembly using binary serialization through [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You should be able to store the full reflected assembly object graph through binary serialization in a file. Following are two quick examples for writing/reading assembly with binary serialization.

Serialize Assembly to a file:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var file = File.OpenWrite("assembly.bin"))
{
    formatter.Serialize(file, assembly);
    file.Close();
}
```

Deserialize Assembly from a file

```
Assembly assembly;
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var file = File.OpenRead("assembly.bin"))
{
    assembly = (Assembly)formatter.Deserialize(file);
    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: all I get is garbage data or info like this:     ÿÿÿÿ          System.UnitySerializationHolder   Data UnityTypeAssemblyName    Ax      :Run, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nulllyName    Ax      :Run, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null         Ax+PROCESS_INFORMATION

Comment: Show your code, I am not sure how you are using it. I have tested the above and it worked fine.

Comment: if (methodInfo.Name == DeliverUs.Name)
     {
                        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                        using (var file = File.OpenWrite("assembly.bin"))
                        {
                            formatter.Serialize(file, type.Assembly);
                            file.Close();
                        }
      //return methodInfo.Invoke(null, DeliverUs.Values);
     }

Comment: I am guessing your code: DeliverUs.Assembly already has the assembly object. Why not serialize that itself. Why are you accessing type.Assembly? May be you need to clarify the use case in little more detail. All I understood from your question was a way to serialize assembly in file. Posted code does that.

Comment: Never mind. I just found some code that loaded the assembly from a resource byte array. Thanks.